# Database living in the past?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have events in my MySQL database wich all have a date. When I perform a SQL query to get all the events in the future, I get an error... Although, the date of the events are in the future. When I change my SQL request to select dates in the past, I get those from the future...
The SQL statement below has worked before, but for some reason it stopped working...

I use this SQL request:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE date >= CURDATE() order by `date`";
```

I get an empty array as result...
However if I change the query to this, I get all the events in my database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE date <= CURDATE() order by `date`";
```

This is my database data. In my opinion, all data are in the future... 
[image]

The format of the `date` table is a default date-type:
[image]

When I ask my server about the time `echo date("Y-m-d");` I get todays date as result...

So where do I make a mistake?

Comment: What type is the date field? I'm guessing if it's not the right type it might cause issues

Comment: I think you must use DATE_DIFF. Maybe I am wrong but I think in firts case mysql compare like a string

Comment: It's the default `date`-format...

Comment: Oh the sql you have shown, you're missing an ` at the end

Comment: The `<= CURDATE()` has worked before, so I don't get why I have to switch...

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE date >= CURDATE() order by `date"; should be $sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE date >= CURDATE() order by `date`";

Comment: If that's not the problem then unfortunately I don't know :/

Comment: Are you sure that your mysql is on the same machine as your web server? Because you pasted PHP code. Try SELECT CURDATE(); instead.

Comment: yes work because maybe date string realy less then current date string.

Comment: I've edited my code with your correction, but unfortunately, it didn't make any difference. Thanks for pointing this out though!

Comment: Can you try by replacing `date >= CURDATE()` by `date >= CURDATE()+0` ?

Comment: Is your PHP correct? I see a missing backtick!

Comment: @dystroy, thanks for your suggestion, but I get a `unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING`-error

Comment: use DATEDIFF : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

WHERE DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE) > 0

Comment: What does `SELECT CURDATE();` show?

Comment: @Louis & Cranio, thanks for you suggestions, but I've corrected the typo. Still no restults...

Comment: Try also to put backticks around the first `date`

Comment: Perhaps it's to do with have the date field called date? That's the only other issue I can see

Comment: @cranio, now you understand my pain

Comment: @Cranio, `SELECT CURDATE();` shows the current date... 2012-06-26

Comment: So CURDATE() is not the issue. Date could be a reserved word, try to put backticks around EVERY occurrence of "date" and tell me.

Comment: @Cranio, backticks didn't work. If I change from `>` to `<`, I get all all the events...

Comment: The problem clearly lies in the use of `>`... Whenever I use this, I get nothing in return. If I use other items (like `<`) I get proper results...

Comment: Have you tried your queries in phpMyAdmin, what was the result? Are you sure you're connecting to the right DB? Also I would avoid using keywords as column/table names in future, tends to end up being a headache eventually.

Comment: The queries in my phpMyAdmin does work fine and I'm connecting to the right database since when I change `>` to `<`, everything seems to work just fine!

Comment: If both greater and less than are working as expected in phpMyAdmin you're not connecting to the right table/db in your php code. Possibly an incorrect server/user connection? dev / prod?

Comment: Or you filter the result in PHP and forgot about it. Try running mysql_num_rows() on your result set directly after your query and see what that says.

Comment: @Louis, no I'm pretty sure I'm connecting to the right database... When I just change my greater then (`>`) to less then (`<`), I get all the results I need. So there is a good connection to the correct database. It's the greater then sign my code is having trouble with...

Comment: Show us more of your code. I've tested what you've shown us and didn't have any problems so it has to be something on your end.

Answer (score 2):

You may be checking the wrong date field. Do you have a created date as well as a scheduled date?

I could be crazy from the cold medicine I am on at the moment, but your date table can't possibly be the date of your calendar items, the id filed is only an int(2), that seems kind of small.

Comment: I only have one column (`date`)... Why can't it be the date of my calendar items? And what's wrong with the structure of the id-table?

Comment: Just guessing here, because this is the only table I see the structure for, but if this is you date field for your calendar, the id field is on an int of size 2, meaning that you will only be able to enter 99 records before it starts having duplicate key errors.

Comment: That's ok! There is a limit planned for 79 records at most!

Answer (score 2):

maybe something simplier? I notice the column name in your table is `date`, which also is the name of a function date() that returns the date part of a datetime value. If thats the case

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar c WHERE c.`date` <= CURDATE() order by `date`";
```

would do the trick. Even if not mysql itself, the gui app youre using (seems like phpmyadmin to me) might get confused.

(btw, you forgot the closing tick of `date` in the order by clause)

Comment: Good catch. I missed that too.

Comment: this was my first guess after not touching mysql for a while, alas it isn't the problem - tested.

Comment: I recreated your data table and did same query on my system. Everything worked as expected, no "enterprise timewarp" effect at all.
Makes me think it might be related to some mysql server compile issue. Is the mysqld a MySQL official binary, or home-built ?

Answer (score 1):

getting an empty set is meaning nothing is found matching.  I would look at your formatting of your date.  The only other thing i was thinking is that it is comparing an unmatched type so just returns an empty set.

Comment: I inserted the data by using the PHP MyAdmin UI, so I guess it's a correct value...

Answer (score 1):

use DATEDIFF :

[DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

WHERE DATEDIFF(date, CURDATE) > 0

Answer (score 0):

Before you make your query, run this one:

```
SET time_zone = '-2:00'; // or whatever your time zone is.
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get your answer... I have to update my SQL query with my time_zone? How wil I get the events in the future?

Comment: I see in values 2013 year - I don't think that the problem in timeZone

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me how or why, but I've truncated my table and re-inserted some data and my query seems to work just fine:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE `date` >= CURDATE() order by `date`";
```

So, despite the fact the problems seems to be solved by truncating my table, I would like to know the answer to the why-question... Anyone can provide me with it?